# 350z auto shifted vibrates

Tags: nissan, vibration, 350z

Hey guys I need help figuring out want is wrong with my automatic shifter for my 2007 350z, when I go over 85 my shifter starts to vibrate real hard and my car shakes abit too, would like to know what could it be thanks

Comment: When you go over 85 kmph?  Over 85 mph *I* would start to shake.

Comment: Over 85mph or around there but the shifter vibrates hard and I can feel the car shaking